# Calling a class method in Python/PySide

Tags: python, pyside, qfilesystemwatcher

I spent longer than I'd care to admit think of a suitable 'question' heading for this topic, as my issue is somewhat hard to articulate.

Here is a quick summary of the situation:

- I'm writing a basic GUI with Python 3.4 and PySide
- I'm using QFileSystemWatcher to monitor a particular file
- When the file is changed, QFileSystemWatcher calls a method, which in turn calls a method within a PySide Class
- All of the above seems to be working perfectly, except the GUI-specific actions detailed in the PySide Class method aren't being executed (I'll explain in more detail below).

Example code:

```
#Establishing the PySide GUI Class
class GUI(QMainWindow, Ui_GUI):
    def __init__(self, parent=None)
        super(GUI, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.Button, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.Run)

    def Run(self):
        print("1")

        self.treeWidget1.clear()
        self.treeWidget2.clear()

        print("2")

        self.label1.setText("Text 1")
        self.label2.setText("Text 2")

        print("3")

        for y in range(0, 5):
            self.treeWidget1.resizeColumnsToContents()

        print("Finished")

#Establish the file monitoring mechanism, *outside* the PySide class
def FileChanged():
    Script = GUI()
    Script.Run()

Paths = ['path/to/file']
Watch = QtCore.QFileSystemWatcher(Paths)
Watch.fileChanged.connect(FileChanged)

#Setting up the GUI
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    showGUI = GUI()
    showGUI.show()
    app.exec_()
```

As I mentioned above, the above code doesn't return any errors. When I change the file (listed in the path), FileChanged does indeed call the Run() method from the GUI class. However, it won't actually **do** any of the 'stuff', it will only execute the print commands in between the 'stuff'.

If I then click on the 'Button' in the GUI, it will execute Run() correctly, and properly execute all the 'stuff'.

My question: is there something I'm missing here? If it's calling the method correctly, and is able to execute the various 'print' commands, why is it not executing the actual 'stuff'?

Thanks!

EDIT 1: I've removed the -do stuff- tags and put in some example code. All the 'stuff' code relates to updating various PySide QLabels, QTreeWidgets, etc.

EDIT 2: I forget the () at the end of the treeWidget clear commands.

Comment: If it's printing 1, 2, and 3 but not doing any of the stuff, then you need to show what the stuff things are. It's most likely that they are to blame.

Comment: That's fair enough, but if they weren't working, surely an error would be raised? At the very least, it would stop the execution, thus preventing it from printing the following 'print'? All the 'stuff' commands are related to clearing QTreeWidgets, populating QLabels, etc.

Comment: It completely depends on that code. Code can easily not do want you want without raising an exception!

Comment: Good point! Unfortunately my current IDE doesn't have a debugger, so I'm not able to step through, but I've updated the original post with some example code. I've also re-directed the FileChanged call to a Test() method, with only a single command (clearing a QTreeWidget), which still didn't work.

Comment: `self.treeWidget1.clear` needs `()` at the end, otherwise it won't work I suspect. `self.label1.setText("Text 1")` should work, providing `self.label1` exists and is a `label`, you can check by doing `print self.label1` and seeing if it prints out `<PySide.QtGui.QLabel object at 0x.......>`.

Comment: My mistake, I forgot the () at the end of the clear commands, as I added them hastily. If I run Run() by clicking the Button, everything works perfectly. All the GUI-related functionality is executed without error, so I really don't think they are the problem. The issue seems to be due to calling the Run() method from an external method, as I can call the Run() method from within the GUI class, and it executes perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Script` object created in the `FileChanged` function has local scope, and will be garbage-collected as soon as the function returns.

If the `Run` slot gets called when the signal fires, it will carry out all of the changes correctly, but you won't get to see any of those changes, because `Script` will be deleted before it is ever shown.

In order to for the example script to begin to make any sense, it would need to be re-arranged to something like this:

```
#Setting up the GUI
if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    showGUI = GUI()

    #Establish the file monitoring mechanism, *outside* the PySide class
    def FileChanged():
        showGUI.Run()

    Paths = ['path/to/file']
    Watch = QtCore.QFileSystemWatcher(Paths)
    Watch.fileChanged.connect(FileChanged)

    showGUI.show()

    app.exec_()
```

Of course, it's possible that your *real* code is nothing like the example in your question (which has numerous other errors preventing it from being run), and so this might be no help. But if that is the case, you will have to post a fully working, self-contained example that properly demonstrates the problems you are having.

Comment: You are a gentleman and scholar! Everything you posted makes perfect sense. I've re-written the GUI setup (as per your instruction above), and the GUI now updates as required. Thanks so much!